# Update/ recalibrate XG Boost, Random Forest, GLM models for external validation

Tags: random-forest, boosting, calibration

I have created XG Boost, Random Forest and GLM models for classification of a binary outcome and now I want to externally validate the models on a different population of over 5000 subjects.

I have gained insight on the importance of calibration and model updating by reading several publications by amongst others Ewout W Steyerberg and Frank Harrell and have been using prof. Harrell's excellent rms package to create calibration curves and extract metrics.

However I can't figure out how to apply updating/ recalibration to my models that seem to perform well but need updating of slope and intercept as I think risk is lower in the new population.

I have found examples of R code to apply to linear models for example in chapter 20 “Updating for a New Setting” of the book "Clinical Prediction Models" by
Ewout W. Steyerberg.

For the below calibration curve for the XG Boost model the intercept is -0.49 and the slope is 1.14.

Could anyone provide insight and preferably R syntax as to how I can apply updating to my models so that when they are used on the current population the updating is "incorporated"?

Thanks in advance!

[image]